# Is it possible to give parameters to program started from batch file?

Tags: java

Can I give parameters to a jar file when I'm opening it with a batch file?

The batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
start java -jar 2D_TestGame.jar
DebugMode = true
```

And this `debug mode = true` line giving a `true` value for line `DebugMode` in program

Comment: Do you mean command line parameters or environment variables?

Comment: i mean, i have a boolean varible DebugMode in Java Main class.
and the question is, can i give a true / false value to that boolean, with a batch file?

when batch file started the game, i need it to gives a value to DebugMode varible

Comment: If you set the DebugMode variable before you start the java application, you should be able to read the value with `System.getenv("DebugMode");` [Environment Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html) are Strings so you need to convert the value.

Comment: you mean i can do it in program, but i need to set that varible with batch file when im starting it

Comment: You can use an environment variable or a command line parameter. Either way, it will always be a string because that's just how it works, and you'll need to convert it to the type you want, and set it to the reference.

Comment: ok thanks, ill try.
how to close this post?

Comment: Maybe wait for an answer, or write one yourself and accept it. It seems like a reasonable request unless you find a duplicate.

Comment: Q: Can I give parameters to a jar file when I'm opening it with a batch file?  A: Sure.  You can pass command line programs to *ANY* Java app, regardless if whether it's packaged as a .jar, or whether it happened to be launched from a .bat file.  Q: can i give a true / false value to that boolean, with a batch file?  A: Sure.  Just remember that parameters are *STRINGS*.  Your app needs to translate text "true" to a boolean. Please read, "upvote" and "accept" HelloWorld123's reply below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page describes how to pass parameters to a Java program's main-method using command line parameters: [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Java-command-line-arguments#:~:text=A%20command%2Dline%20argument%20is,array%20passed%20to%20main(%20)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Java-command-line-arguments#:%7E:text=A%20command%2Dline%20argument%20is,array%20passed%20to%20main(%20)).

As you can see, that is actually the reason why you always have the String[] args as a parameter of the main-method.

A working solution for you would be:
`java -jar 2D_TestGame.jar true`

And then the following in the main-method of your Java-program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      if (args.length > 0) {
         // Convert the String ("true" or "false") to a boolean
         DebugMode = Boolean.parseBoolean(args[0]);
}
```

(Assuming you have already described boolean DebugMode as a class-variable

Comment: The code you posted is not fully valid, consider fixing that.

Comment: @criztovyl thanks for the hint, should be fixed now. Was responding from my phone and therefore wasn't able to run it to check it